# Inverse of parametric function

Tags: calculus, general-topology

Maybe this is an easy question, but I can't figure it out!

What is the inverse mapping of:

$f(t) = (\cos(t), \sin(t))$,

where $f: [0, 2\pi) \to S^1$

Does one just invert the components separately?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Formally, you have $f^{-1}(\cos t, \sin t)=t$. Maybe more practical is the formula 
$$f^{-1}(x,y)=
\begin{cases}
\arccos x \quad \text{if }\, y\geq 0\\
2\pi-\arccos x \quad \text{if} \, y<0,
\end{cases}
$$
assuming $x^2+y^2=1$ (for instance).